# Where does is published com.earldouglas#xsbt-web-plugin?

Tags: scala, repository, sbt, spray, xsbt-web-plugin

I am trying to update [spray](https://github.com/spray/spray) project, and got

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.earldouglas#xsbt-web-plugin;1.0.0-M7: not found
```

I have added Typesafe repository

```
resolvers ++= Seq("spray repo" at "http://repo.spray.io",
"Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/")
```

But still can not resolve this dependency.

Comment: What do you mean with "I am trying to update spray project"?

Answer (score 4):

For versions prior to 1.0.0, xsbt-web-plugin was published to [Sonatype](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin_2.10_0.13/) and synced to Maven Central.  For 1.0.0 and later, it is published to [Bintray](https://bintray.com/earldouglas/sbt-plugins/xsbt-web-plugin/view).

> unresolved dependency: `com.earldouglas#xsbt-web-plugin;1.0.0-M7`

Can you update your dependency to `1.0.0` from `1.0.0-M7`?  Better yet, consider updating to `2.3.0` or later.

*project/plugins.sbt:*

```
addSbtPlugin("com.earldouglas" % "xsbt-web-plugin" % "1.0.0")
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code in the build.sbt worked for me

```
resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("earldouglas", "sbt-plugins") 
addSbtPlugin("com.earldouglas" % "xsbt-web-plugin" % "2.2.0")

resolvers += Resolver.url(
  "bintray-earldouglas-sbt-plugins",
  url("http://dl.bintray.com/earldouglas/sbt-plugins"))(
  Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

Comment: xsbt-web-plugin is included in the community plugin repository, so no additional `resolvers` are needed.